# Php include_path error:Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, xampp

I am getting the following error:

"PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '-' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0"

I dont know how to solve this error.
And also i am trying to run Php code :

```
"<? php phpinfo(); ?>"
```

But i am getting blank page

Comment: Remove space from your syntax. <?php echo phpinfo();?>

Comment: Change your code "<? php phpinfo(); ?>" to <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: ok, but error i am getting in error log file how do i solve it?
 and i am using xampp